# Conditionally applying className to a react component depending on where the component is used

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have two components ThisComponent and ThatComponent. Inside those components, I render a third component ACoolThirdComponent. What I'm trying to achieve is set the class of the div depending on whether I use the ACoolThirdComponent in ThisComponent or ThatComponent.

Is this possible?

ThisComponent

```
export const ThisComponent = () => {

   return (
      <ACoolThirdComponent/>
   )

}
```

ThatComponent

```
export const ThatComponent = () => {

    return (
        <AThirdCoolComponent/>
    )

}
```

Then, the last third ACoolThirdComponent

```
export const ACoolThirdComponent = () => {

    /* Psuedo code */ 

    if this component is used-in/called from ThisComponent set a class "this-cool-class"
    if this component is used-in/called from ThatComponent set a class "that-awesome-class"

    return ( 
      <div className={aNiceDynamicClassBasedOnTheAbove}></div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it passing a prop so you can detect it:

```
export const ACoolThirdComponent = ({ className }) => {



    return ( 
      <div className={className}></div>
    )
  }
```

So when you call it you can pass him the className you want:

```
export const ThatComponent = () => {

    return (
        <AThirdCoolComponent className="whatever"/>
    )

}
```